# Python to Excel using xlxswriter: Formula fails

Tags: python, excel-formula

I'm trying to use pythons xlsxwriter package to set a formula in excel. Simple formulas (addition, sum) are working, but when I am using the INDEX()-formula, an error within the xlsx-file occurs and the formula is missing.

Any idea what I am doing wrong?

```
import xlsxwriter

workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook('hello.xlsx')
sheet1 = workbook.add_worksheet(name='Sheet 1')
sheet1.write('A1',5)
sheet1.write('A2',10)
sheet1.write_formula('D3', '=A1+A2')
sheet1.write_formula('E3', '=SUM(A1:A2)')
sheet1.write_formula('F3', '=INDEX(A:A;1)')

workbook.close()
```

Answer (score 1):

Replacing

```
sheet1.write_formula('F3', '=INDEX(A:A;1)')
```

by

```
sheet1.write_formula('F3', '=INDEX(A:A,1)')
```

solved the issue. In the US notation arguments are separated by ",", in the german notation they are separated by a ";".

Comment: It is good that you found the issue. Note, for future reference, there are some formula debugging steps in the docs: [Dealing with formula errors](https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/working_with_formulas.html#dealing-with-formula-errors)